# GMSPlace Auto Complete Always return same Place coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

the return of auto Autocomplete always give the same value.

```
  func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
      print("Place name: \(place.name)")
      print("Place coordinate: \(place.coordinate)")
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

this the value I always get:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -180.0, longitude: -180.0)
```

this is the code I use to call the searchViewController for address:

```
func showSearchViewController() {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self
    
    // Specify the place data types to return.
    let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue))
    autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
    
    // Specify a filter.
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .address
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
    
    // Display the autocomplete view controller.
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to resolve this you need to specify in Fields `GMSPlaceField` the Data you want.

for example if you wanna the name and coordinates you need to put:

```
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | UInt(GMSPlaceField.coordinate.rawValue))
autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
```